# calculate '$a$' so that the vectors are a linear combination

Tags: vector-spaces

How to calculate the value of 'a' so that $$ \overrightarrow{u} = \{1,3,a\} $$ is a linear combination of $$\overrightarrow{v} = \{1,-1,0\} $$ and $$ \overrightarrow{w} = \{2,1,1\} $$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Find $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$ such that

$$u=\alpha v+\beta w$$
from the first two components and then find $a$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If $(1,3,a)$ is a linear combination of $(1,-1,0)$ and $(2,1,1)$, then $(1,3)$ is a linear combination of $(1,-1)$ and $(2,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find a linear combination of $\{1, -1\}$ and $\{2, 1\}$ that makes $\{1,3\}$.
2. Apply the same linear combination to $\{1, -1, 0\}$ and $\{2, 1, 1\}$.
3. See what $a$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $A=(\overrightarrow{u},\overrightarrow{v},\overrightarrow{w})$. If $\overrightarrow{u}$ is a linear combination of $\overrightarrow{v},\overrightarrow{w}$, then $\det(A)=0$ from which you can get $a=?$.

Comment: Oh.... a = 1 ??

Comment: @Adelson, $a=4/3$